# Error en CONSULTA SQL CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server, sql, subconsultas

Estoy trabajando actualmente con una base de datos en SQL Server, dicha Base contiene 13 tablas y a partir de ellas he generado una consulta de forma distribuida que me muestra 4 campos (OrderID, Employee, ContactName, Total). Dicha consulta es la siguiente:

```
select o.OrderID,concat(e.FirstName,' 
',e.LastName),c.contactName,sum(d.quantity*d.unitprice) 
from Orders o 
inner join Employees e on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
inner join customers c on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
inner join "order Details" d on d.OrderID = o.OrderID
group by o.OrderID, concat(e.FirstName,' ', e.LastName), c.contactName;
```

Pero ahora quiero agregar un quinto resultado a esta consulta que se llame "BONO AL EMPLEADO" la cual tendrá un SI, si cuya orden que generó el empleado, el importe es mayor a $1000, de lo contrario tendrá un NO.

Pero al tratar de hacer esto tengo como resultado un NULL, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
select  
case sum (quantity * unitprice)
when 1000 then 'si'
end
from "order details" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

LO HE CONSEGUIDO

```
select d.OrderID,concat(e.FirstName,' 
',e.LastName),c.contactName,sum(d.quantity*d.unitprice) 
case
when sum(d.quantity*d.unitprice) <=1000 then 'no'
when sum(d.quantity*d.unitprice) >=1000 then 'si'
end as Bono_al_empleado
from Orders o
inner join Employees e on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
inner join customers c on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
inner join "order Details" d on d.OrderID = o.OrderID
 group by d.OrderID, concat(e.FirstName,' ', e.LastName), c.contactName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
case sum (quantity * unitprice)
when 1000 then 'si' else 'no'
end
from "order details" ;
```

Comment: Sólo me ha salido un dato del campo con un "no"